# Add user role from identity to custom database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, identity

I have a function that finds a user in a database and adds a role. The role is added in the Asp.net identity table. I am trying to update the role that also exists in another table in a different database. I've written the logic but I'm not quite there yet. So my question is, how do I correctly add the role that is being added to the aspnetuserroles table, to my custom table located in a different database? Any assistance would be helpful.

```
public async Task<bool> AddARole(string email, string role)
    {
    //get the users email address and role from the Person table
    var currentUser = _context.PersonTable.Where(x => x.Email == email && x.UserRole == role);

        var UserManager = _serviceProvider
                            .GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var userExists = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        if (userExists!= null)
        {
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
             //update the person's role
             _context.PersonTable.Update(currentUser);
        }
        _identityContext.SaveChanges();
        //save the changes
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. I just updated the question. So I'm trying to update the role that is added into the aspnetuserroles table to the custom table existing in another table.

Comment: Look at the type of `currentUser`. My guess is that is wrong. It probably should use `.Single()` instead of `.Where()`. But you never even use `currentUser`...so I dont know whats going on here.

Comment: Hi Brad. Thank you for your reply. I'm using currentUser when updating. What is the correct way of writing this? I've tried Singe() instead of Where(), and I'm getting null for currentUsers.

Comment: Anyone willing to help?